# How to call method having parameters (object sender, EventArgs e )

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, parameter-passing, function-calls

In my wpf application, I've MonthView class where this method is defined, which takes selected date from the calendar and shows respective dayView window for that date.

```
public void calItemSelectedDate(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime d;
        if (sender is DateTime)
        {
            d = (DateTime)sender;
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime.TryParse(sender.ToString(), out d);
        }
        DayView Activity = new DayView(d);
        Activity.Show();
        this.Hide();
     }
```

Now, In my CustomView class, I've created instance of dayView where I want to pass selected date.

```
DateTime p = Globals._globalController.getMonthViewWindow.calItemSelectedDate(object s, EventArgs e); // here it shows error
DayView d = new DayView(DateTime p);
```

so, please suggest ways to call that 'calItemSelectedDate' method so I can pass appropriate datetime parameter to my DayView.

Comment: try DateTime p = Globals._globalController.getMonthViewWindow.calItemSelectedDate(this, null);

Comment: @DatRid Still showing error at 'this' keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method to refering to is an *event handler* and not a best choice for direct calling. 
What I would do in this case, is :

```
//A PROPERTY THAT SAVES SELECTED DATE VALUE
public DateTime SelectedDate {get;set;}

//A METHOD THAT SHOWS ACTIVITY 
public void ShowActivity(DateTime date) {
    DayView Activity = new DayView(date);
    Activity.Show();
    this.Hide();
}

public void calItemSelectedDate(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime d;
    if (sender is DateTime)
    {
        d = (DateTime)sender;
    }
    else
    {
        DateTime.TryParse(sender.ToString(), out d);
    }

    SelectedDate = d;

    ShowActivity(d);
 }
```

and from your class where you want to call it:

```
DateTime p = Globals._globalController.getMonthViewWindow.SelectedDate;
DayView d = new DayView(p);
```

Comment: I tried your code but, it shows error while passing to DayView.

Comment: The error is "a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property"

Comment: check your accessibility public/static... among these calls:  Globals._globalController.getMonthViewWindow

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I wrote these two lines inside class but outside constructor. But after moving into constructor, it works fine.